# Rails webpacker import issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I am trying to use a javascript library called [jsViewer](https://kukudocs.com/jsViewer) in my rails application.

If I import the library directly in my HTML, I have no problem using the library.

E.g HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/javascript/JSViewerLoader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/javascript/docxjs/DocxJS.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

However, I receive developer console errors when I try to use the library when imported via webpacker.

[image]

E.g application.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;

import Rails from 'rails-ujs';
import Turbolinks from 'turbolinks';
Rails.start();
Turbolinks.start();

import '../src/javascript/JSViewerLoader.js'
import '../src/javascript/docxjs/DocxJS.bundle.min.js'
```

Why does this happen and how do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

With javascript pack in rails 6, you can manually add your js libraries using two simple steps

- add js files to `app/javascript/packs`
- and then, in your `app/javascript/packs/application.js` you can import it using

```
require('packs/JSViewerLoader.js');
```

Or, you can use `yarn` to install the js file first. Then, import it later. ( It seems that your library does not support this kind of installation ) For ex

```
# Run this on your terminal
yarn install aJsLibrary

# add this line to your app/javascript/packs/application.js
window.aJsLibrary = require('aJsLibrary');
```

Comment: what's the difference between using require vs. import?